# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' in python3 during run caffe example

Tags: python

when I run these code:

```
untrained_style_net = caffe.Net(style_net(train=False, subset='train'),'/content/caffe/models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/bvlc_reference_caffenet.caffemodel', caffe.TEST)
untrained_style_net.forward()
style_data_batch = untrained_style_net.blobs['data'].data.copy()
style_label_batch = np.array(untrained_style_net.blobs['label'].data, dtype=np.int32)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
in ()
----> 1 untrained_style_net = caffe.Net(style_net(train=False, subset='train'),'/content/caffe/models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/bvlc_reference_caffenet.caffemodel', caffe.TEST)
2 untrained_style_net.forward()
3 style_data_batch = untrained_style_net.blobs['data'].data.copy()
4 style_label_batch = np.array(untrained_style_net.blobs['label'].data, dtype=np.int32)

2 frames
/usr/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py in func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
622 @_functools.wraps(func)
623 def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
--> 624 return func(*args, **kwargs)
625 # Avoid closing the file as long as the wrapper is alive,
626 # see issue #18879.

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

how can I solve it?

Comment: Format your code, because in the current form nobody can understand it.

Comment: Also add more details on your question.